# How can I select the minimum version (ie x.x.x.x) stored in a varchar column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, version

I've tried the obvious `select min(version) from t` but this wouldn't work as the engine considers (and rightly so) that the string '1.12.0.0' is smaller than '1.2.0.0', which is obviously not the case when it comes to version numbers.

I know I can easily split the 4 numbers dynamically (using either computed columns or a view) and then I can just use `select top 1 row from myview order by a asc, b asc, c asc, d asc`

... but I was curious to know if there was an easier way to achieve this

Comment: Can you store the minor versions as fixed-length?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql I guess

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare software versions using SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364242/how-to-compare-software-versions-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 3):

If your version numbers contain at most 4 numbers separated by a dot, you can abuse the [`parsename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) function:

```
select  top 1 *
from    Versions
order by
        cast(parsename(Version, 4) as int)
,       cast(parsename(Version, 3) as int)
,       cast(parsename(Version, 2) as int)
,       cast(parsename(Version, 1) as int)
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/41bef/14/0)

Comment: don't you think version 1.2.0.0 is earlier than 1.12.0.0?

Comment: @SirRufo: Good point, the version numbers have to be cast to `int` for sorting.  Updated in answer.