# SQL Server Filter by Version

Tags: sql-server

Alright, say I want to filter a table which has stored version numbers in X.X.X format.

This is very easy if I just want to filter a single version number.

```
where version = '3.12.92'
```

as an example.

But what if I am looking for a certain *RANGE* of versions, such as from '2.21.23' to '3.12.92?' What would be the least complicated but reliable solution for filtering by a version range?

EDIT: It is too late to change the formatting of the table. The table is years old with MILLIONS of entries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare software versions using SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364242/how-to-compare-software-versions-using-sql-server)

Comment: the real solution is to fix your table design, then your search would be trivial. NEVER combine multiple values in a single column, you will forever have problems splitting them apart. If you had each segment of your version in a different column you could easily do this.

Comment: Too late for that, the table I am searching has millions of entries.

Comment: Are all version strings always in the format `x.y.z` (three parts, two decimals)?

Comment: best short term bet is to get a temp table/derived table/table variable/cte that contains every version in your range and do a join.  Long term, I'd look to a presisted indexed computed column where you can encode these in a int or big int, where you use leading zeros and put an index on it.  like: "3.12.92" becomes: "300120092"  and 1.2.3 becomes "100020003"

Comment: Yes they are all in that format (but there can be two parts one decimal ones).

Comment: What are the maximum values in each of the three parts?

Comment: is the format always x.xx.xx ? or would 3.01.01 stored as 3.1.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to separate the version bits into separate columns for a quick fix you can use the following query

```
DECLARE @version VARCHAR(100) = '3.12.92';

SELECT  REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(@version) , 1)) AS FirstBit
       ,REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(@version) , 2)) AS MiddleBit
       ,REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(@version) , 3)) AS LastBit
```

Result:

```
FirstBit    MiddleBit    LastBit
   3           12          92
```

Your Where clause for where first bit = 3 would look something like....

```
WHERE REVERSE(PARSENAME(REVERSE(@version) , 1))  = '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

if there are always three at most two digit numbers separated by dots you can write a function to convert `x.y.z` into an integer of the form `x*10000 + y*100 + z`.