# SQL Server compare numbers after decimal point

Tags: sql-server

We have some numbers values in SQL server database such like `7.11 and 7.6`. 
Actually `7.11 is later version than 7.6`, when using "`max(vernum)`" in SQL server, it will return `7.6`. How can we let SQL server return `7.11`?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare software versions using SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364242/how-to-compare-software-versions-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go read the **[official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)** .

> By default, SQL Server uses rounding when converting a number to a
>   decimal or numeric value with a lower precision and scale

Try This

```
SELECT MAX(Version) OVER(ORDER BY CAST(PARSENAME(version, 2) AS INT) DESC,CAST(PARSENAME(version, 1) AS INT) DESC) Version, Version    
FROM yourTable
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1982f28021b6ff71e0f417ac889d0b8b)

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, you could use a `TOP` query here, using ordering by casting the major and minor version numbers to integers:

```
SELECT TOP 1 version
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CAST(LEFT(version, CHARINDEX('.', version) - 1) AS INT) DESC,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(version, CHARINDEX('.', version) + 1, LEN(version)) AS INT) DESC;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a more shorter answer of this.

```
with cte as (
    select  7.11 as ver
    union all
    select 7.6
)select top 1 ver from cte
      order by parsename(ver, 2), parsename(cast(ver as float), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
CREATE TABLE #Numbers (value float);
INSERT INTO #Numbers (value)
VALUES (7.1);
INSERT INTO #Numbers (value)
VALUES (7.6);
INSERT INTO #Numbers (value)
VALUES (7.11);
INSERT INTO #Numbers (value)
VALUES (1.1);
INSERT INTO #Numbers (value)
VALUES (6.5);

SELECT Top 1 VALUE , Cast(PARSENAME(VALUE,1) as Int) AS DECIMAL_ONLY 
FROM #NUMBERS
order by 2 desc
```